# Sitemap and url parameters for google webmaster

Tags: codeigniter, sitemap, url-parameters, google-search-console

I am looking for some info about setting `URL Parameters` according to how my Codeigniter app works, and also creating a sitemap for it.

`http://www.test.com/en` -> Home page

`http://www.test.com/result?query=mountain` -> **Result** being a function inside a controller to where `query` input data is sent. I think **query** is a `Specifies` parameter type to set as a `URL Parameter`

`http://www.test.com/result?query=mountain&filter=spain` -> I think **filter** should be a `Narrow` parameter type because without, it shows all the *mountain* results from all the countries. This parameter will show only from *spain*

`http://www.test.com/result?query=mountain&filter=spain&page=2` -> **page** should be a `Paginates` parameter type that paginates the results.

`http://www.test.com/result?query=mountain&filter=spain&sort=viewed` -> **viewed** should be a `Sorts` parameter type

`http://www.test.com/image/123asd` -> **Image** is a function inside the same controller as result. It loads details/tags/comments about the image clicked.

I've read the documentation on Google's URL Parameters, but what I don't know is: do I have to set the controller also to the parameter that to be added?. I mean, do I have to set it like so:

> **query**     -   6:12 PM (0 minutes ago)     **Specifies**  **Every URL**
>
> **filter**    -   6:12 PM (0 minutes ago)     **Narrows**  **Every URL**

or like this

> **result?query**  -   6:12 PM (0 minutes ago)     **Specifies**   **Every
>   URL**
>
> **result?filter**     -   6:12 PM (0 minutes ago)     **Narrows**     **Every
>   URL**

and so on...

What about the sitemap, should I generate it? How if I don't control the query input and the results page?

Comment: 3 basic question how should I setup the url paramerters, should I generate my sitemap, how?

Answer (score 2):

The real answer here is simple: you typically don't need to or want to tell Google to index search or browse pages or their variants of sort/pagination or otherwise.  Google used to recommend that you exclude these pages from their index because they start looking like duplicate content (typically all the content present is also present elsewhere on the site).  Google has gotten a lot smarter recently.  There is an exception, however.

I used to work for a company that had a site that sold consumer electronics.  By far the most popular queries were  , like "canon cameras".  We implemented this as a browse page with a twist -- the page contained title, meta-description,  tag, and some hand-crafted content that was specific to the results page.  The URL would be something like `http://example.com/digital-cameras/?brand=canon` and these are pages we most definitely wanted Google to know about and index (and for a while, we did quite well on searches for those terms).  So there's nothing wrong with adding them.

Otherwise, you can use Google webmaster tools to exclude parameters Google should ignore, such as sort and pagination parameters.  You may also be able to do this in `robots.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate the topic... We were discussing this one yesterday...  we sell items by the gallons..

page 1 10 - 200  product.aspx?id=123

page 2 200 - 500  product.aspx?id=123&page=2

page 3 500 - 1000  product.aspx?id=123&page=3
and so on...

do we want to add these multi number pages to the site map (page 2, 3 , ...) ...  each page has a different gallon range on it?   with the most expensive 10000 gallons being on page 10...

when i search the url in quotes with this at the end product.aspx?id=123&page= it returns page ten top in the results..with 2 and 4 following when i do show omitted results...

I didn't really have answer... after typing this out i'm leaning towards yes...  you want google to know about them..  it should be considered duplicate content...?

in my mind if someone searches say 500 gallon item..   google would return a product page result at the top of the listings and not a page3 category page with 10 items only one of them 500 gallons...  that's my thoughts...  i'm curious as to yours..  i find it to be an interesting question  ...

also they show up as webpage microdata in webmaster tools...

any thoughts are appreciated..